# Org-mode, how can I export my images in different float enviroment?

Tags: org-mode, latex, images

I need to export some images in different type of float in latex (i.e. `\begin{map}`).

An example of latex code is [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/387467/manual-label-to-figure).

How can I define image attributes in org-mode to achieve that?

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot. Org mode hardwires the word "figure" in the LaTeX exporter and there is no user-settable option to change it.

Comment: if what @NickD says is correct, you could still define a "filter" to replace "figure" for "map".

Comment: That's true: I  always forget about [filters](https://orgmode.org/worg/exporters/filter-markup.html) primarily because I've only used one once or twice.

Comment: I should not replace all "figure" with "map" but some of them. Is it possible to flag some images and apply the "map" filters on them?

Comment: Possible but harder.

Comment: I found a temporary solution with tac, awk, sed: ```tac article.tex | awk 'f && sub(/begin{figure}/,"begin{map}"){f=0} /#fig2map#/{f=1} 1' | tac|sed 's/#fig2map#//g'>article.tex
```. I insert in my caption a special keyword (#fig2map#) and the script replaces "figure" with "map" in the corresponding \begin statement. And finally, it removes "fig2map# keyword.